# Open posts in editor in the 'Text' mode by default

Tags: editor, code

I have a few posts where there are some code segments. When I try to make small edits in the post, it opens in the 'Visual' mode and all the non-alphanumeric characters (e.g. `>`) are converted to their html equivalents (e.g. `&gt;`). Also I lose all the indentation. I would like to open all posts in the 'Text' mode by default. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line to your theme's functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_editor', create_function( '', 'return "html";' ) );
```

Use "html" to set the Text editor tab as default (as shown above), or "tinymce" to set the Visual editor tab as default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently using the free blogging service. My blog has this address: http://thespeakingsonu.wordpress.com. Is it possible to edit functions.php here too?

Comment: You won't be able to edit PHP files with a Wordpress.com hosted site; that's only possible with a self-hosted site. Last I checked, there was no option to set the Text editor as default with Wordpress.com.