# Wordpress, content editor default type

Tags: wp-admin

How to set text as default editor type in Wordpress? Now it is visual and some content (like php content in the widgets) will be change if the mode is changed from visual to text.

Comment: The similar question is already answered: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156259/126702](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156259/126702)

Comment: In addition to Milan's comment, you can disable the visual editor altogether on a user-by-user basis via user settings.  IMO, there should never be a need for the visual editor... styling is already taken care of by the site's CSS so WP content should only be text and images.

Comment: It does not affect to widget editor.